# Angular 2 component access context - selector vs route

Tags: angular, components, selector

I access the same component via routes and via selector. So, '/projects' routes to the projects list component, AND

```html
<projects></projects>
```

uses the component as well. I want to know which method was used to access the component. 
Bottom line - the route access is a full page, and the component access is in a widget. If the access is via widget, I want to change the way a few things work.

Comment: For Angular 2+ use [tag:angular], for angular 1.x use [tag:angularjs]

Answer (score 2):

You can check the routed URL

Inject `private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute` in the component's constructor and you can get the url like below

```
this.activatedRoute.url.subscribe(urlPath=>{});
```

check the `urlPath` if `projects` then its via routing else it is via selector

Comment: Thanks. I figured I might need to do that. I'm actually abstracting this structure and I don't want to force the route to match the entity. I was looking instead for a flag that tells HOW the component was called, as opposed to checking the path. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

Try a bit hacky way to do it..
Add a input variable `@Input() isRoute: boolean = true;` to your component and set its default value to true.
When using selector, use it like this:
`<projects [isRoute]="false"></projects>`.
Now when this component opens in route, it will set `isRoute` to true else it when this components opens via selector, `isRoute` will be false. :)